# React app failed to load content to browser

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying build cbioportal-frontend on my system but getting error when used webpack --watch:
"ERROR in /home/trainee_biocos/RecatApp_Examples/cbioportalTestRun/cbioportal-frontend-1.16.0/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts(15165,15):
TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'name'.
Version: typescript 2.7.2"
but reactapp is build in dist/ folder 
when "npm run start" is used same error appears but gives "build successfully completed". when browsed to "localhost:3000/" no content gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try to restart yarn/npm from cmd for the project after following below steps. 
it may be solve your issue.

Another suggestion you can try.
- Rename the variable to be something else, other than name.

- The error arises because the variable 'name' already exists on the global 
  scope
- Check for duplication of variable name.
- Check TypeScript version.
- use export {}; put export in your class if it is missing.

Comment: since this portal is cloned from git there are many files, do not know which file to add export{} in?.

Comment: Insert "export" just before variable name declaration where you are getting error like export { PARA_NAME }

Comment: sorry! i am getting error in a library file of typescript module "lib.dom.d.ts", when i add export{} just before declaration many errors get generated.

Comment: check version of typescript. remove it and install latest version from npm for type script

Comment: tried installing latest version and this increased number of errors.

Comment: In my context cbioportal this error seems ok. https://github.com/cBioPortal/cbioportal-frontend/issues/1534 refer this link for more details.